# NTP sync on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, ntp

How would you make a Windows Server 2008 server sync with free ntp servers on the Internet?

What free programs would do this?
How do you configure them? (I need it to sync every 30sec as the server's clock drifts very very fast ~1sec per 40min)

**Update:** See [follow up question](https://superuser.com/questions/308163/ntp-sync-doesnt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need any outside software, just use this document to show you how to configure it natively:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816042 (read the section "Configuring the Windows Time service to use an external time source")

Comment: As a note, if you are doing this on a Microsoft domain, a relatively easy way to synchronize the clients is to add this line to your logon batch file: net time \\servername /set /yes . Of course, if they never logon, it will not work. You can also set clients to use it in group policy.

Comment: That's a bit out of date.  `net time` has been deprecated for over 5 years now.  The questioner did ask for *NTP* synchronization, moreover.  `net time` uses an RPC protocol, not NTP.  The way to do this _with NTP_ on a domain member workstation is `w32tm /resync` and have the domain member run the `w32time` service, which (being a service and not a logon script) doesn't need logon events in order to work.

Comment: I just said "easy", not best.

Comment: Notice to also set the UpdateInterval under the Config section, as explained in the comment to the answer in this question: http://superuser.com/questions/308163/ntp-sync-doesnt

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks for marking the answers. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

More appropriate source from MS:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731191%28v=WS.10%29.aspx

"current"/specific to Server 2008 & Server 2008 R2

> To configure the Windows Time service on the first forest root domain
>   controller
>
> - Log on to the first domain controller that you deployed.
> - At a command prompt, type the following command, and then press ENTER:
>
>   ```
>   w32tm /stripchart /computer:<target> /samples:<number> /dataonly
>   ```
> - Open User Datagram Protocol (UDP) port 123 for outgoing traffic, if needed.
> - Open UDP port 123 for incoming NTP traffic.
> - You can use a different port, if you prefer.
> - Type the following command to configure the PDC emulator, and then press ENTER:
>
>   ```
>   w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:<peers> /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:yes /update
>   ```